# Batch Submenu in submenu, command goto Main menu execute all commands in submenu

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, menu

I am building like ultimate batch file with commands I use on a daily basis, let's go to the problem. So far I tried changing and having multiple variables, tried to break it apart as much as I could put " on almost everything but is it still the same.

So first menu work ok, so does the second one, but the submenu (submenu11) in second menu/submenu (submenu1) when I put in 0 as variable to get back to main menu every command in submenu11 gets executed. I tried to explain the best I could.

The code is down below you please try and give me some new perspective.
Thank you.

p.s. Reboot was commented out

```
@ECHO off

:start
CLS
ECHO
ECHO Main Menu
ECHO 1. Windows
ECHO 0. Exit
ECHO.
set /p choice=

if "%choice%"=="1" goto submenu_1
if "%choice%"=="0" goto exit

:submenu_1
ECHO
ECHO Windows
ECHO 1 - Test Mode
ECHO 0 - Main Manu
ECHO.
set /p a=

if "%a%"=="1" goto submenu11
if "%a%"=="0" goto start

:submenu11
@ECHO on
ECHO
ECHO Test Mode
ECHO 1 - Enable Test Mode
ECHO 2 - Disable Test Mode
ECHO 0 - Main Menu
ECHO.

set /p b=

if "%b%"=="1" ECHO
ECHO Enable Test Mode
ECHO.
bcdedit -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON
ECHO
ECHO Windows will restart
ECHO.
Pause
::shutdown -r -t 10

if "%b%"=="2" ECHO
ECHO Disable Test Mode
ECHO.
bcdedit.exe -set loadoptions ENABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING OFF
ECHO
ECHO Windows will restart
ECHO.
Pause
::shutdown -r -t 10
if "%b%"=="0" goto start
goto submenu_1

:exit
```

Comment: You never check if b is equal to zero until the end. Of course it will execute all that code.

Comment: Even if you answer 1 it will run all that code. You have no goto commands to tell it to go back to the submenu until the end as well.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment, but can you help me further I am kinda lost.

Comment: `if "%b%"=="1" (do something)` Build code block

Comment: so you are telling me that if i change lets say: if "%b%"=="1" start HTTP://192.168.0.1 then it should work?

Comment: Batch files are basically executed line by line, so you need to state `if` and `goto` to change that default behaviour; you have some of those but not enough, so some lines are executed unintentionally; you also do not control what to happen in case an invalid entry has been provided by the user, so simply the next line is executed...

Comment: i keep getting this if "0" == "1" bcdedit -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS and do not realy know what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off&cls
:start
cls
ECHO Main Menu
ECHO 1. Windows
ECHO 0. Exit
ECHO.
set /p choice=

if "%choice%"=="1" goto submenu_1
if "%choice%"=="0" exit
goto:error

:submenu_1
cls
ECHO Windows
ECHO 1 - Test Mode
ECHO 0 - Main Manu
ECHO.
set /p a=

if "%a%"=="1" goto submenu11
if "%a%"=="0" goto start
goto:error

:submenu11
cls
ECHO Test Mode
ECHO 1 - Enable Test Mode
ECHO 2 - Disable Test Mode
ECHO 0 - Main Menu
ECHO.

set /p b=

if "%b%"=="1" (
ECHO Enable Test Mode
ECHO.
bcdedit -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON
ECHO
ECHO Windows will restart
ECHO.
Pause
rem shutdown -r -t 10
)

if "%b%"=="2" (
ECHO Disable Test Mode
ECHO.
bcdedit.exe -set loadoptions ENABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING OFF
ECHO
ECHO Windows will restart
ECHO.
Pause
rem shutdown -r -t 10
)

if "%b%"=="0" goto start

:error
echo Invalid Answer
```

Comment: Thank you, i did not even consider to put it in ()